# Como hacer un Swipe able Tabs en ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic-framework

Estoy creando una aplicacion web usando las tabs que vienen por defecto en ionic, pero al momento que quiero utilizarlo de una manera mas parecida android puro usando el swipe, estos no generan ese evento

Segun tengo entendido podria usar `ionic-super-tabs`, pero lo eh intentado instalar y no logro hacerlo, la version de ionic que estoy usando es 6.0.3, no se si eso es lo que genera el inconveniente, no se si existe otra o alguna forma usando ionic para crear este efecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale justo estaba buscando integrar esa parte en mi proyecto te muestro como lo hice y te comento que estoy utilizando la versión de Ionic 6.20.1 y son las 3 tabs que te genera por defecto:

1.- Instalar **SuperTabs**: `npm i --save @ionic-super-tabs/angular`

2.- En el `app.module.ts` importa el ***SuperTabsModule*** Linea 6 y en la 13 no olvides agregar el `.forRoot()`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.- En el `tabs.module.ts` (*src/app/tabs/tabs.module.ts*) también se importa el ***SuperTabsModule***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4.- En ese mismo directorio, vamos a nuestro `tabs.page.ts` para agregar las configuraciones, de momento las default, más adelante las puedes modificar.

Tu componente `tabs.page.ts` se vería así:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SuperTabs } from '@ionic-super-tabs/angular';
import { SuperTabsConfig } from '@ionic-super-tabs/core';
import { Tab1Page } from '../tab1/tab1.page';
import { Tab2Page } from '../tab2/tab2.page';
import { Tab3Page } from '../tab3/tab3.page';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tabs.page.scss']
})
export class TabsPage {

  @ViewChild(SuperTabs) superTabs: SuperTabs;

  tab1Page = Tab1Page;
  tab2Page = Tab2Page;
  tab3page = Tab3Page;

  config: SuperTabsConfig = {
    dragThreshold: 10,
    allowElementScroll: false,
    maxDragAngle: 40,
    sideMenuThreshold: 50,
    transitionDuration: 300,
    shortSwipeDuration: 300,
    debug: false,
    avoidElements: false,
  };
}
```

En general importas las *SuperTabs* y su *configuración*, también importas las *tabs*  ya que cuando hagas el swipe, tiene que saber a que tab dirigirse, finalmente el objeto *config* de tipo *SuperTabsConfig*, son las configuraciones por defecto que tiene en su [documentacion](https://zyra.github.io/ionic-super-tabs/getting-started/angular/) , puedes probar activando el debug y ver en consola los cambios que se hacen.

5.- Paso final, dentro del mismo directorio, modificaremos nuestro `tabs.page.html` únicamente es usar los componentes del superTab:

La propiedad ***activeTabIndex*** toma el indice del tab con el que quieras que incie la app, en mi caso la primera pestaña entonces el indice es 0.

Puedes cambiar el color del componente `<super-tabs-toolbar>` usando el atributo color y probar con "**primary**", "**warning**", "**danger**", "**default**", "**dark**" quizá haya más fueron los que probé.

Para posicionarlo ya sea en la parte superior o inferior, puedes modificar el "slot" del componente `<super-tabs-toolbar slot="bottom">` `<super-tabs-toolbar slot="top">`

Y en el componente `<super-tabs-container>` solo configurar nuestra ruta de las paginas, antes definidas en nuestro archivo `tabs.page.ts` paso 4.

En mi caso mi `tabs.page.html` quedo de esta manera:

```
<super-tabs activeTabIndex="0" [config]="config">
  <super-tabs-toolbar slot="bottom" color="default">
    <super-tab-button>
      <ion-icon name="grid-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
    </super-tab-button>
    <super-tab-button>
      <ion-icon name="hammer-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Proyects</ion-label>
    </super-tab-button>
    <super-tab-button>
      <ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Settings</ion-label>
    </super-tab-button>
  </super-tabs-toolbar>

  <super-tabs-container autoScrollTop>
    <super-tab>
      <ion-nav [root]="tab1Page"></ion-nav>
    </super-tab>
    <super-tab>
      <ion-nav [root]="tab2Page"></ion-nav>
    </super-tab>
    <super-tab>
  <ion-nav [root]="tab3page"></ion-nav>
</super-tab>
```

Espero te haya servido deberías tener un resultado similar a este:

https://global.discourse-cdn.com/ionicframework/original/3X/0/6/06dd1f2cc4de9e8a0b0718dd608ad0697d79e93a.gif

Fuentes:

[Documentacion](https://zyra.github.io/ionic-super-tabs/getting-started/angular/)

[Foro Ionic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-swipeable-tabs-are-now-here/84266)

[Proyecto de ejemplo en Git](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-super-tabs-example)

Comment: Gracias, ahora me surgio otra pregunta, como puedo hacer que solo se vea en Home page que no se vea entre otros componentes?